# Closed-form solution of $\max_{x_1,\cdots,x_N}\sum_{n=1}^Na_nx_ns.t. 0\le x_n\le 1,\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n=C$.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider a linear optimization problem as follows.
$$\max_{x_1,\cdots,x_N}\sum_{n=1}^Na_nx_n\\s.t. 0\le x_n\le 1,\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n=C$$where $C$ is constant, $a_1\ge a_2\ge\cdots\ge a_N\ge0$. By using simplex method, I find that the optimal solution is always that $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_C=1$, $x_{C+1}=\cdots=x_N=0$.

Can anyone give me some hints to prove it? Really, I have no idea how to prove it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If $x_1<1$ , then increasing it whilst reducing any other $x_i$ would certainly not decrease the expression being maximised. Similarly consider $x_2,x_3, ...$